# SPFieldUserValue : Unable to Get user using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, user-profile

I'm using PowerShell Script to get user login name

```
try {
    $CreatedByUser=""
    $CreatedBy= $($version["Author"])

    if($CreatedBy -ne $null){
       $CreatedByObj = New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPFieldUserValue($w,$CreatedBy)

       $CreatedByUser = $CreatedByObj.User.LoginName
    }
}
catch {
    $CreatedByUser=""
}
```

Please check value for CreatedBy variable is

**411;#Akshay Nangare,#domain\Akshay,#Akshay@domain.com,#,#Akshay Nangare**

Please suggest something

Comment: it should be `SPFieldUserValue`, is the spelling correct ?

Comment: Actual while writing the question I had make that mistake. Sorry for that. I will update question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
try
{       
    $CreatedByUser = $version.CreatedBy.User.LoginName      
}
catch
{
    $CreatedByUser=""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that your catch block will never catch an exception as it will throw a non-terminating error. For this to work as you expect it to you should change the global ErrorActionPreference variable:

```
try
{  
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" 
    $CreatedByObj = New-Object Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPFieldUserValue($w,$CreatedBy)
    $CreatedByUser = $version.CreatedBy.User.LoginName
}
catch
{
    $CreatedByUser=""
}
finally {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
}
```